# Time between two button clicks (Java)

Tags: java, button, time

I want to print the time between two buttons clicks (ButtonA and ButtonB). This is part of my code (which doesn't work because only the current time is printed):

```
class ClicksReporter implements ActionListener {

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  long startTime = 0;
  long endTime = 0;

  if ( e.getActionCommand().equals("ButtonA") ) {
    System.out.println("ButtonA was clicked");
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
  } 

  if ( e.getActionCommand().equals("ButtonB") ) {
    System.out.println("ButtonB was clicked");
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - startTime;
    System.out.println("Time: "+endTime);    
  }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startTime` and `endTime` are local variables that are lost once the method returns. So, every time `ButtonB` is clicked, the value of `startTime` is zero. You need to make start time a field of the class instead.So, something like this:

```
class ClicksReporter implements ActionListener {
  long startTime=0;
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  if ( e.getActionCommand().equals("ButtonA") ) {
    System.out.println("ButtonA was clicked");
    this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
  } 

  if ( e.getActionCommand().equals("ButtonB") ) {
    System.out.println("ButtonB was clicked");
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 - startTime;
    System.out.println("Time: "+endTime);    
  }
}
```

Also, make sure that the same instance of `ClicksReporter` is set as the action listener for both button A and B.